# Save attribute of a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, attributes, switch-statement

I need some help with my code.
I have an UIAlert that pops up the first time that you open the app, in that pop up I have two buttons and the user will choose one of those. I want the app to remember what button the user chose to execute some code or other. The thing is I have this code right here :

```
-(void)changeLabel{


        progressView.progress += 0.25;
    scan.hidden = YES;


        if (progressView.progress == 1 ) {
            label.hidden = YES;

            progressView.hidden = YES;

            [timer invalidate];

            imagesText.hidden = NO;


            int randomNumber = arc4random() % 4;

            switch (randomNumber) {
                case 0:


                    imagesText.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];


                    break;

                case 1:


                    imagesText.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];


                    break;

                case 2:

                    imagesText.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];

                    break;
                case 3:

                    imagesText.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"];

                default:
                    break;

        }
    }
}
```

So I want to make it in some way that if the user selected the first button the app will do the switch between cases 0,1 and 2 and if he selected the second button it'll do it between 3 and others. But I want the beginning of the code to be the same for both cases.
I tried some stuff but it doesn't work how I wanted.
Thank you for your help!

UPDATE: I got the error fixed. So right now I have this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alert"] ]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"alert"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        UIAlertView *alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Welcome!" message:@"Select your language" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Button1" otherButtonTitles:@"Button2", nil];



        [alerta show];
        [alerta release];

    }


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];



   progressView.progress += 0.25;
    scan.hidden = YES;


    if (progressView.progress == 1 ) {
        label.hidden = YES;

        progressView.hidden = YES;

        [timer invalidate];

        imagesText.hidden = NO;

        int randomNumber;

        if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Button1"]) {

             randomNumber = arc4random() % 3;

        }else if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Button2"]) {

             randomNumber = arc4random() % 3 + 3;

        }

        switch (randomNumber) {
           //CODE
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that all that code is  supposed to be called from :

```
 - (IBAction)scan:(id)sender {

    label.hidden = NO;
    imagesText.hidden = YES;
    progressView.hidden = NO;


    progressView.progress = 0;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(alertView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

So I changed the @selector to the alertView one and now when I press the button that execute all the code it gives me that SIGABRT error. Any ideas why?
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You don't have (or you're not showing) a selector called "alertView"

Comment: So how can I make all that code work when I press the button? Because it needs to be inside the uialertview right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing now -- the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method is a delegate method that's called by UIAlert when you click a button, you don't call it explicitly (if that's what you're trying to do in the timer method). You need to create a property buttonTitle so it can be used across different methods -- the only thing that needs to be in the delegate method is self.buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];  Then you would use buttonTitle like I showed in my answer.

Comment: Oh I got it now, I'll try tomorrow and I'll tell you if it worked. Thanks for your time

Comment: Do I have to declare buttonTitle before or something? I tried making a property on the .h file I put: @property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *buttonTitle; and then I synthesized it but I get again the SIGABRT error when I press the button that execute everything

Comment: Oh, I forgot to change the selector. It's all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user chooses a button, you need to populate a property with some unique value of the button, like its title or a tag.  Once you have that, you can put an if statement before your randomNumber definition -- something like this:

```
if (buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"First Button") {
        int randomNumber = arc4random() % 3; // Gives choices of 0,1, or 2
    }else if (buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Second Button"){
        int randomNumber = arc4random() % 3 + 3; // Gives choices of 3,4, or 5
    }

     switch (randomNumber) .... (rest of your code)
```

In the else-if statement the +3 will ensure that the choices in the switch statement will start with 3 and go up from there (I don't know how many other choices you have).

Comment: I understand what you said, but how do I make that property for the button? because right now the buttons appear on the UIAlertView.Sorry if it's a stupid question but I still kind of newby.

Comment: In the UIAlertView delegate method,alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:, you'll get the index of the button clicked.  You could save that index to a property.

Comment: Alright, when I put all the code together it says : "Use of undeclared identifier 'randomNumber'" Do i have to make a variable with randomNumber somewhere? if so, where?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's my fault -- you should declare the variable above the if statement, so have a line that's just: int randomNumber;  Then in the if statement just use randomNumber without the "int" in front of it.

Comment: That worked, I updated the questions. Check it out if you have some time :)